# my projectile changes direction mid-air Pygame help needed

Tags: python, pygame

Design: ninja who throws kunais.

Problem: the kunai if thrown to the left of the screen, she keeps consistently flipping until it leaves the screen and gets deleted.

CODE (only the projectile file aka the knife) :

```
import pygame

class Projectile(pygame.sprite.Sprite):

    def __init__(self,player):
        if player.face_direction == "RIGHT":
            self.direction="Right"
        else:
            self.direction="Left"
        super().__init__()
        self.player=player
        self.velocity=4
        self.image=pygame.image.load('assets/kunai.png')
        self.image=pygame.transform.scale(self.image,(80,50))
        self.rect=self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.x=player.rect.x+20
        self.rect.y=player.rect.y+50
        self.origin_image=self.image



    
    def remove(self):
        self.player.all_projectiles.remove(self)
    
    def move(self):
        if self.direction=="Right":
            self.image=self.origin_image
            self.rect.x+=self.velocity    
        elif self.direction=="Left":
            self.image=pygame.transform.flip(self.image,True,False)  
            self.rect.x-=self.velocity

        if self.rect.x>1080 or self.rect.x<-30:
            self.remove()
```

Answer (score 2):

You only need to set the image to the correct facing once, in `__init__`. If you've done that, the `move()` method doesn't need to do as much work on each frame. You can do a similar thing with the `velocity` of the projectile, setting a negative value if you need to move to the left, greatly simplifying the logic in `move()`:

```
class Projectile(pygame.sprite.Sprite):

    def __init__(self,player):
        super().__init__()

        self.player = player
        self.image = pygame.image.load('assets/kunai.png')
        self.image = pygame.transform.scale(image,(80,50))
        self.velocity = 4
        self.rect=self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.x=player.rect.x+20 # you might want this to depend on direction
        self.rect.y=player.rect.y+50
        self.origin_image=self.image # you may not need this

        if player.face_direction == "RIGHT":
            self.direction = "Right"
        else:
            self.direction = "Left"
            self.image = pygame.transform.flip(self.image,True,False) # do the flip here
            self.velocity = -self.velocity                            # negate the velocity

    def move(self):
        self.rect.x += self.velocity                  # now this sum can be unconditional
                                                      # and no image manipulation is needed
        if self.rect.x > 1080 or self.rect.x < -30:
            self.remove()
```

You may not need the `direction` attribute any more, since `move` doesn't use it. And regarding `remove()`, you might not need this method if you're removing yourself from a PyGame `Group`, rather than from a list. Sprites already keep track of the groups they're in, and you can use the `kill()` method you've inherited to remove yourself from all groups automatically. This might mean you don't need to keep a reference to the `player` any more.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like the problem:

```
self.image=pygame.transform.flip(self.image,True,False)
```

You keep flipping `self.image` at every cycle. You should just flip it once when the kunai is first thrown.

A way to get around this is to create separate images: normal and flipped. Then set the `self.image` to the correct image depending on direction.

Try this code:

```
import pygame

class Projectile(pygame.sprite.Sprite):

    def __init__(self,player):
        if player.face_direction == "RIGHT":
            self.direction="Right"
        else:
            self.direction="Left"
        super().__init__()
        self.player=player
        self.velocity=4
        self.image=pygame.image.load('assets/kunai.png')
        self.image=pygame.transform.scale(self.image,(80,50))
        self.rect=self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.x=player.rect.x+20
        self.rect.y=player.rect.y+50
        self.origin_image=self.image.copy()  # new image non-flipped
        self.imageflip=pygame.transform.flip(self.image,True,False)  # flipped image
  
    def remove(self):
        self.player.all_projectiles.remove(self)
    
    def move(self):
        if self.direction=="Right":
            self.image=self.origin_image
            self.rect.x+=self.velocity    
        elif self.direction=="Left":
            self.image=self.imageflip 
            self.rect.x-=self.velocity

        if self.rect.x>1080 or self.rect.x<-30:
            self.remove()
```

Comment: yeah, I thought about it too and added some function to check if it needs to flip or not but it didn't work. I'm stuck figuring how to fix that basically

Comment: Though this is correct, The work in `move()` should really be done in the `__init__()` as in @Blckknght 's answer.